# How to use Rscript command line tool to build a book in bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Because of the cross-reference feature, I am using `bookdown` instead of `rmarkdown` to generate dynamic reports. I have more than one reports to generate, so I drafted an `R` script to call `bookdown:render_book` in a `for` loop to generate all the reports. Unfortunately, it errored. For simplicity, I build one minimal example:

The `bookdown` file to render (saved as `index.Rmd`):

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r test}
ext_var
```
````

The `build.R`:

```
ext_var <- "test.html"
bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", output_file = ext_var) # it will call `rmarkdown::render`.
```

When using following commands: `Rscript build.R`, it will generate the following error messages:

```
$ Rscript build.R
Error in rmarkdown::render(main, output_format, ..., clean = clean, envir = envir,  :
  'ext_var'
Calls: <Anonymous> -> render_cur_session -> <Anonymous>
Please delete _main.Rmd after you finish debugging the error.
```

Then I changed my `build.R` to use `rmarkdown::render` instead:

```
ext_var <- "test.html"
rmarkdown::render("index.Rmd", output_file = ext_var)
```

There won't be any error. So I guess there might be some issues to fix.

`sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936  LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936 LC_NUMERIC=C                              
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RevoUtils_11.0.0     RevoUtilsMath_11.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.17    bookdown_0.7    digest_0.6.15   rprojroot_1.3-2 backports_1.1.2
 [6] magrittr_1.5    evaluate_0.10.1 stringi_1.1.7   rstudioapi_0.7  rmarkdown_1.10 
[11] tools_3.5.0     stringr_1.3.1   xfun_0.1        yaml_2.1.19     compiler_3.5.0 
[16] htmltools_0.3.6 knitr_1.20
```

Also filed [an issue #592](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/592) at `rstudio/bookdown` repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [you have discovered by yourself](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/592), the problem was caused by the default `render_book(clean_envir = TRUE)` in your case.

However, please also note that `bookdown::render_book()` is not supposed to work with output formats other than those in the **bookdown** package. In other words, you should not expect the `html_document` format to work with `render_book`. If you need the feature of cross-references, please use those output formats of which the names end with `2` in the **bookdown** package (e.g., `bookdown::html_document2`), and these formats are designed to work with `rmarkdown::render()`. See [Section 3.4](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/a-single-document.html) in the bookdown book for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Bookdown needs more than a single Rmd file, so the error is not with `Rscript` but with your setup.

If you have a proper bookdown setup such as

```
edd@rob:~/git/bookdown-demo(master)$ ls  
01-intro.Rmd        05-summary.Rmd       _bookdown.yml  preamble.tex 
02-literature.Rmd   06-references.Rmd    index.Rmd      README.md 
03-method.Rmd       book.bib             LICENSE        style.css  
04-application.Rmd  bookdown-demo.Rproj  _output.yml    toc.css    
edd@rob:~/git/bookdown-demo(master)$
```

then running

```
Rscript -e 'bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd")'
```

does what you expect.  I am unsure bookdown supports given the output file down `rmarkdown::render()` as you generally specify it in `_bookdown.yml`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is okay to run a single expression with `Rscript`. But the real point here is to put that `bookdown::render_book` expression in an `R` source script, and then use `Rscript` to run the script. In this way, if I have to use some variables generated in the script to set the output file name of bookdown (see my example), it will error.

Comment: As my answer tried to explain, I am not so sure you can vary this the way you want to. The output file name is a _constant_ in the YAML file.

Comment: You might miss some point. The output file name could be customized in the `bookdown::render_book` expression by specifying the argument `output_file`, because basically that function will call `rmarkdown::render`, which accepts the `output_file` argument to set the output file name. Also see [this](https://rdrr.io/cran/bookdown/man/render_book.html) for more info.

Comment: No, the point is that you see `...` passes down to `markdown::render()` and assume it would just take a filename _and thereby alter bookdown behaviour_. Please show where it says that bookdown can have variable output filenames.  I still think this fails for a more fundamental reason that you think, but I am done here as I said my piece, and do not need your tone here. Good luck.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Hopefully, @Yihui Xie will comment on this.

Answer (score 2):

After a careful research on `bookdown::render_book` function, I have found the real cause of this error. This function has set one argument `clean_envir`, and its default value is `!interactive()`. That is why the environmental variables disappear when knitting with `bookdown` with command line tool. The fix to this problem is easy, just set `clean_envir` as `FALSE`, i.e.,

```
ext_var <- "test.html"
bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", output_file = ext_var, clean_envir = FALSE)
```

Then it works.